# Add whitespace to Google Chart Label

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Recently Google Charts enabled labeling and had this to say about the resulting layout

"If the label is too big to fit entirely inside the bar, it's displayed outside" https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart

However, I am discovering that if the label is a string, and has spaces, it is breaking into two lines if nearing the threshold of being "too big".  See my example below.

Does anyone know of a whitespace solution to make it a solid string?  Or any other idea?

http://jsfiddle.net/gbzLB/32/

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
data.addColumn('number', 'Percent');
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'});
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'style'});
data.addRows([
    ['Greek', 55, '216 Votes - 72%', 'color: #FFCC00'],
    ['Italian', 5, '15 Votes - 5%', 'color: #FF6688'],
    ['Polish', 16, '48 Votes - 16%', 'color: #33CCFF']
]);

var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.querySelector('#chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, {
    height: 150,
    backgroundColor: {fill: '#F2EFFB'},
    hAxis: {title: "Percentage", maxValue: '100', gridlines: {
            color: 'black'

    },
    width: 480,
    legend: {
        position: 'none'
    }
});
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you replace the whitespace with `&nbsp;` and set `allowHTML` in chart.draw's options?

Comment: Good idea, but does not seem to be working.  Don't know if my use of allowHTML is improper. http://jsfiddle.net/gbzLB/35/

Comment: `allowHtml` isn't a valid option for most charts.  I suspect that this is a bug in the annotation code.  You can file a bug report on it here: http://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/list